# Is Spring Data Elasticsearch supporting the reactive model?

Tags: project-reactor, spring-data-elasticsearch

I was consulting the documentation of [Spring Data Elasticsearch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-async) store and I came across this line:

> Refer to store-specific documentation for more details on reactive support.

Although I'm already in the elasticsearch store documentation, I didn't find any further information about reactive support. Where can I find further informations on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reactive support is available in the current master branch (which currerntly is milestone version 3.2.0 M4) and will be released as part of the Spring Data Moore release.

You find the [documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.0.M4/reference/html/)

Comment: I have tried as your documents said what to do to use ReactiveRepository but stills does not work. It seems the repository bean was not created. (I used version 3.2.0.RELEASE)

Comment: how have you set this up and configured?